# Move Focus on an Input based on user's click?

Tags: html, focus

I have a homepage, where you can either click **Sign Up** or **Create An Account**

If you click either link it takes you to the same page, Sign up and Create An Account live on the same page.

What they want is the Focus when you click Sign Up to be in the Username Input field but if you click Create An Account the Focus First Name Input field.

How can I determine where the Focus should be based on what a User clicked on the previous page?

Comment: Does a click on one of those two options cause the page to be reloaded?

Comment: so they live on the same page? THIS sounds where ever they put the focus it wont matter because the user is going to be confused.  there needs to be some type of highlight on the form they are inserting data into like a green border and the other form greyed out. I would hide the other form to eliminate confusion. The design is the problem imo not which field is focused. rarely unless you have some very unique styles :focus can a user even tell what field is in focus unless THEY are actually putting it into focus themselves. I'm only saying this because I don't think that is going to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden field or querystring. And on the document.ready of signup/create account page you can use focus().

HTH
Ali

Answer (score 0):

You could transfer this data with the url, js is able to read Strings after the Hash Sign '#' in the URL. Usually this is used for scrolling, but you can use it for focusing.

```
<script>
function getHash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  return hash.substring(1); // remove #
}
function init() {
    document.getElementById(getHash()).focus();
}
</script>
<body onload="init();">
<input id="a" /><br/>
<input id="b" /><br/>
</body>
```

The Url would be

```
server.com/login.html#focusedElementId
```